# Ubuntu 17.04 "configure vpn" option is disabled

Tags: vpn

It is 17.04.

i clicked wireless- edit connections and add vpn. Then put credentials and now ,

Add vpn is disabled and vpn is not working. I cant connect where vpn resources belong to.

[vpn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvsu4.png)

Comment: Have you installed the vpn extensions for network-manager?

Comment: Yes. i installed  `sudo apt-get install -y network-manager-openconnect-gnome network-manager-openconnect network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome vpnc vpnc-scripts` `udo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
`

Comment: If you have your configuration file, you don't need to use the "Configure VPN" menu item.  From the NetworkManager icon go to Edit Connections...   -> Add  -> Import a saved VPN configuration. It worked for me on 17.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use the "Configure VPN" option. If you have your configuration file, from the NetworkManager icon go to Edit Connections... -> Add -> Import a saved VPN configuration. It worked for me on 17.04. If you don't have a configuration file, go to Edit Connections... -> Add ->  OpenVPN.

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 18.04 also. UI design issue? This has been going on a long time.