# Unable to connect VPN in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, vpn

I have been trying to connect VPN on ubuntu 17.10, but there is a problem. Every time I click connect, it shows the message "Network connection failed, activation of the network connection failed" and I don't know why.

I followed the same procedure in this video to establish the VPN connection:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nKP6M0xIuqE

Can anyone help?

Comment: Assuming you have openvpn installed try this...https://askubuntu.com/questions/922087/ubuntu-17-04-configure-vpn-option-is-disabled/945511

Comment: No one can advice you without you providing logs of the openvpn. Kill all instances of the openvpn and start it from terminal like `sudo openvpn --config /path/to/your/config_file`

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to connect to VPN with the settings app of Ubuntu 17.10 too. But i've found a terminal solution for connecting to VPN. 
This code connects you to the connection that you made in settings :

```
nmcli con up your_connection_name --ask
```

If you can't remember the connection name you can use this code :

```
nmcli connection show
```

And for disconnecting use this code :

```
nmcli con down your_connection_name
```

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me: "$ nmcli con up "VPN connection SUE 2" --ask
Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown reason"

Comment: However it was helpful to identify the problem in combination with the information that the network manager prints its logs to syslog: https://askubuntu.com/questions/556951/how-to-see-log-of-nmcli-network-connection-failed-unknown-reason